# Axios CORS Vultr S3 "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

So I'm trying to make a request with axios to an image on an Vultr S3 Object Bucket so I can convert it to a blob and use it in a package I'm using.

However, despite the url's being public and you being able to access them in the browser, make a request with axios triggers a CORS error. What is strange though is the response code is 200 still.

Here is the error (I've censored the urls and such.);
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://laravel-valet.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

As you can see by the image below, the request is successful and the content-length is correct, so I'm not really sure what the issue is.
[image]

I've also tried experimenting with the fetch API incase this was just some weird thing with Axios, but it appears that even with fetch in "no-cors" mode it just returns an empty response.

Hopefully someone can explain the issue for me here, as I'm fairly confident it isn't on my end but since I'm using Vultr for S3, it doesn't seem like they offer any way to allow domains or disable CORS so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you missing a header that's required? Also maybe check if you can make the call in an external program like Postman to make sure it's not your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CORS configuration using [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd).

First, create a .xml file that contains the CORS-configuration (more about that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors))

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <ID>Allow WebFont for example.com</ID>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>86400</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Then, upload the configuration using this command:

```
s3cmd setcors cors-config.xml s3://bucket-name
```

Answer (score -5):

You need to add headers to you your server side code.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: I can't change the server side code because it's hosted on a Vultr S3 bucket. They're the ones with the server side code.

Comment: Then you can't do much about it